# How can I use a nullable list where in linq in Entity Framework code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a problem to filter a status column in my table:

```
public class QuestionInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public QuestionStatus Status { get; set; }
}

public enum QuestionStatus : byte
{
    None = 0,
    NeedEdit = 1,
    Blocked = 2,
    Accepted = 3,
    Checking = 4
}
```

I want to filter my questions by the list of status that is nullable and when `filterList` is null, I want to select all for example:

```
List<QuestionStatus> filterList = new List<QuestionStatus>();

var questions = (from x in context.QuestionInfoes 
                 where filterList?.Contains(x.Status) 
                    && x.Score > 10 select x).ToList();
```

or:

```
var questions = (from x in context.QuestionInfoes 
                 where (filterList == null ? true : filterList.Contains(x.Status))
                    && x.Score > 10 select x).ToList();
```

I get this syntax error in query one:

> C# - Cannot implicitly convert type bool?

I get this error from query two:

> System.NotSupportedException: unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Atitec.OffseeAPI.DataBase.Models.Games.QuestionsOfKing.QuestionStatus, Atitec.OffseeAPI.DataBase, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.
>   Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can i use nullable list where in linq in entity framework code first?

As you already discovered, you can't (*not supported* exception).

The solution is to use conditional `Where`:

```
var query = context.QuestionInfoes.Where(x => x.Score > 10);
if (filterList != null)
    query = query.Where(x => filterList.Contains(x.Status));
var result = query.ToList();
```